# Is ΔV in ΔU = ΔH - pΔV always a positive number?

Tags: thermodynamics

I know that $ΔU$ and $ΔH$ can be both positive and negative, but what about $ΔV$?
I presume $ΔV$ can be both positive and negative as $w=-pΔV$, pressure always positive, and $w$ can be positive or negative, hence $ΔV$ must be able to be either positive or negative.

Comment: See, there is only so much space around here. If something increased in volume ($\Delta V>0$), then obviously something must have decreased.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and never write "+ve" or "-ve" again.

Comment: @Loong I once had a student write "NRG" in a question response. When asked what it was, they replied that it was their abbreviation for "energy."

Comment: @Loong Out of curiosity, do you know where this cancerous trend of using "±ve"s stems from? I've never seen a textbook using these notations and when I was a student those also hasn't been used at all.

Comment: @andselisk It's definitely been circulating for at least 15 years. And I saw college freshmen doing it, so I suspect that it started in high school (or earlier).

Comment: @andselisk from a quick googling, supposedly its medical shorthand to speed up writing positive or negative, with the ve at the end being the ending of positive and negative. I don't see why + and - on their own wouldn't suffice without tacking on extra letters that could easily be confused for some sort of abbreviation, but thats all the explanation I could find.

Answer (score 1):

The equation you wrote is correct only for the changes in U, H, and V between two thermodynamic equilibrium states, and only if the pressure in the initial and final thermodynamic equilibrium states is the same value.  If the pressure is not the same in the two states, then the equation should read $\Delta U=\Delta H-\Delta (pV)$.  Also, the equation $w=-p\Delta V$ is valid for calculating the work done on a system only if the only kind of work done is p-V work, and only if the pressure is constant over then entire path between the initial and final  thermodynamic equilibrium states.  With regard to $\Delta V$, the change in volume will be a positive number if the system (such as a gas) is expanded, and will be negative if the system is compressed.  That is the definition of expansion and compression.

Comment: Is there a difference between $\Delta U \text{and}\Delta E$

Comment: In many books, $\Delta E$ includes the change in kinetic energy and the change in gravitational potential energy of the system.  So, they write $$\Delta E=\Delta U+\Delta (KE)+\Delta (PE)=q+w$$In many cases, though, the changes in kinetic energy and potential energy don't contribute.